# where does the feeling of shame come from?

Tags: soul, emotions

according to our sources, shame is unique to humans (Duties of the Heart [2:5](http://dafyomireview.com/article.php?docid=414) "reflect on the feeling of shame with which man alone has been endowed").

It does not exist in animals. Is shame a spiritual feeling stemming from the higher soul of humans or is it merely an emotion which is unique to humans. If the former, what exactly is it? What is the spiritual or otherwise mechanism behind it as to why we feel shame.

Comment: "it seems shame is unique to humans. We don't seem to find this by animals" Source?

Comment: https://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/animal-emotions/201403/do-dogs-really-feel-guilt-or-shame-we-really-dont-know questions this assumption. See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emotion_in_animals and https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2575323/ and http://www.emory.edu/LIVING_LINKS/publications/articles/deWaal_2011b.pdf.

Comment: @mevaqesh those articles are based on the assumption that man is no different from an animal.

Comment: וּמוֹתַר הָאָדָם מִן הַבְּהֵמָה אָיִן

Comment: @Loewian in context there just means both share the same fate (death) under the sun. ie in this world

Answer (score 4):

The Orehot Tsaddikim (Shaar 3) writes that shame is unique to humans since it always accompanies intellect (unique to humans):

> אמרו חכמים: השכל הוא הבושה, והבושה הוא השכל...וכן כל בעלי חיים זולתי האדם – אין להם בושה, הואיל ואין להם חכמה.
>
> The sages said: the intellect is shame, and shame is the intellect...And all other creatures besides humans have no shame, for they lack intelligence.

Numerous sources in turn equate the intellect and the soul, e.g. Ohr HaHayyim to Leviticus (18:2)

> השכל שהיא הנשמה

And Arvei Nahal (Genesis derush 2):

> והנה ידוע שהשכל הוא הנשמה

(Although admittedly, these latter two sources do not discuss the connection between shame and the intellect.)

Comment: if the intellect=shame then why arent we always in a state of shame? obviously the O.T. is only saying that intellect is required for feeling shame. not that the two are equal to each other

Comment: @DonielF https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/82208/where-does-the-feeling-of-shame-come-from#comment253132_82208

Comment: @ray Where did he say otherwise? "Shame...always **accompanies** intellect" was the phrase he used - not that it *is* intellect, but that it *accompanies* it.

Comment: @DonielF so then how does it answer the question about where shame comes from? any idea? i tried to ask mevaqesh but got no answer.

Comment: @ray It means intellect *causes* shame, not that it *is* shame. Never confuse the cause and the effect as being the same thing.

Comment: @DonielF so then this has absolutely nothing to do with the question

Comment: @ray You asked where shame came from. He answered that it comes from intellect. That is, the ability of intellect produces the feeling of shame. I honestly didn't think this was that hard of an answer to understand.

Comment: @DonielF i asked what is the root of shame not what makes shame possible. it seems he does not want to answer my comments. though he upvotes every word u say

Comment: @ray Isn't the root of shame and what makes shame possible the same thing? (Maybe he thinks I'm doing a good job defending his answer?)

Comment: @DonielF not at all. i am asking what is this feeling from. i.e. the mechanics of it.

Comment: @ray First, I'm not sure that's implied in your question. Maybe edit to clarify? And second, is that not a question for Biology.SE?